# Why does my springMVC cannot get models from front-end pages?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I use @RequestBody in Controller to make the front-end json inject into my back-end entity automatically, but when I print the members of the entity, all of them are null. I search for some solutions, some suggests changing the Spring version to 4.2.4 can work, some says ommiting `contentType:"application/json"`,  but I still cannot get the properties after doing those. So how can I solve the problem? I try to add `consumes= "application/json"`as the following comment, still in vain. Maybe using MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter can only transfer model to json but cannot do conversely? Should I add more MessageConverters?

There are getters and setters in my models. Here are the excerpts of java code, jsp, applicationContext.xml and pom.xml:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changeNewslist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(value = "update/create", notes = "update/create", httpMethod = "POST", produces = "application/json")
public Integer changeNewslist(
        @ApiParam(value = "newslist", required = true)@RequestBody Newslist newslist,
        // newslist is the model I wanna get
        @ApiParam(value = "1-update 2-create", required = true) Integer operation) {
    System.out.println("**********" + JSON.toJSONString(newslist));
    System.out.println("**********" + operation);
    Integer res = 0;
    if (null != newslist){
        if (operation == 1) {
            newslist.setModifytime(new Date());
            res = this.getNewslistService().updateByPrimaryKeySelective(newslist);
        }
        if (operation == 2) {
            newslist.setCreatetime(new Date());
            res = this.getNewslistService().insertSelective(newslist);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

```html
    $("#wid").on("change", function () {
        wid = $(this).val();
        newsObj.wid = wid;
    });

    $("#sitename").on("change", function () {
        sitename = $(this).val();
        newsObj.sitename = sitename;
    });

    $("#keyword").on("change", function () {
        keyword = $(this).val();
        newsObj.keyword = keyword;
    });

    $("#nextpageCount").on("change", function () {
        nextpageCount = $(this).val();
        newsObj.nextpagecount = Number(nextpageCount);
    });

    $("#weight").on("change", function () {
        weight = $(this).find("option:selected").html();
        newsObj.weight = Number(weight);
    });

    $("#url").on("change", function () {
        url = $(this).val();
        newsObj.url = url;
    });

    $(".status").on("click", function () {
        status = $(":checked:eq(1)").attr("id").split("-")[1];
        newsObj.status = Number(status);
    });

    $("#formSubmit").on("click", function () {
        // newsObj.operation = 1
        console.log(newsObj);
        $.ajax({
            url: '../list/changeNewslist',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType:"application/json",
            // contentType:'text/html;charset=utf-8',
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                newslist: newsObj,
                operation : 2
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                // location.href = './newslist.jsp'
            }
        })
    });
```

```html
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"
          class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
            <list>
                <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bolaa">
        <!-- <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>-->
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

```html
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What is Newslist ? Is it model ? Then it should have setters and getters to recieve these values.

Comment: Use  consumes= "application/json" too

Comment: I used consumes= "application/json" just now, and there were also setters and getters in models, but it still couldn't work. @Sumesh TG

Comment: Are you using @RestController?

Comment: No, should I try it? @Sumesh TG

Comment: sure. You are calling ajax request. So you need to design rest api in server.

Comment: But the problem is the json from request cannot be transfered into model, not problem of response. @Sumesh TG

Comment: In sysout just print newslist.toString();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176381/discussion-between-saeron-meng-and-sumesh-tg).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 @ApiParam(value = "newslist对象", required = true)@RequestBody Newslist newslist,
```

to

```
@ApiParam(name="newslist", value = "newslist对象", required = true)@RequestBody Newslist newslist,
```

Comment: Sry, @ApiParam is the annotation of Swagger-ui, not relavent to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is wrong use @ApiParam

**@ApiParam is for parameters. It is usually defined in the API Resource request class.**

Example of @ApiParam:

**/users?age=50**
it can be used to define parameter age and the following fields:

paramType: query

name: age

description: age of the user

required: true

@ApiModelProperty is used for adding properties for models. You will use it in your model class on the model properties.

Example:

model User has name and age as properties: name and age then for each property you can define the following:

For age:

type: integer,
format": int64,
description: age of the user,
Check out the fields each denote in the swagger objects:

@ApiModelProperty- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#529-property-object

@ApiParam - https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#524-parameter-object